# TeeChart Pro VCL TSeriesBandTool does not work with TDBChart

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have upgraded from Delphi 7 with TeeChart Pro VCL 7.07 to Delphi XE5 with TeeChart Pro VCL 2013. TSeriesBandTool worked perfectly in the old version, but does not seem to work in the new version. I have created a test  and found that TSeriesBandTool works well with TChart in V2013 but not with TDBChart. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're using TeeChart Pro, you purchased it and should have support available from the vendor. Have you contacted them?

Comment: I did contact them and am waiting for an answer. I discovered in the meantime that if I create a new TDBChart with TSeriesBandTool, it works perfectly, but the bands do not show on the 'old' existing charts. Am I missing something simple? I wouldn't want to recreate all the old charts!

Comment: I've just tested the `TSeriesBandTool` in a `TDBChart` with RAD XE and TeeChart v2013.09 and it seems to work fine. So please, edit your question adding a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)